# Некорректное отображение ImageView в CardView

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, cardview

Пытаюсь сделаю cardview в котором на всю ширину и длину будет натягиваться изображение.
Если я напишу такой xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light_gray"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
        
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
        
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
        </RelativeLayout>
```

то изображение корректно отображается на закругленных краях cardview, но мне помимо картинки, надо отобразить еще текст и поверх самого самой картинки View c полупрозрачным цветом, чтобы изменить общий тон картинки. Я сверстал это так

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light_gray"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/light_gray">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/unselectedTransparentLayer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/color_unselected_object_transparent_layer"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/primary_font"
                android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
                tools:text="VIP 10" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

В таком случае я сталкиваюсь с проблемой некорректного отображения картинки на закругленных гарях cardview

[image: На углах появляются какие-то отступы]

По углам появляются какие-то отступы белого цвета. Как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: Скорее дело в CardView - оно плохо умеет отображаться с цветами с прозрачностью. Попробуйте вместо полупрозраного фона у вьюхи поверх ImageView на сам ImageView добавить ваш цвет. Это будет атрибут `tint` - высока вероятность, что так CardView не будет глючить

Comment: Замените RelativeLayout на Framelayout